# reading and writhing an image (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import cv2

img =cv2.imread('OIP.jpg')

cv2.imshow("oip" , img)
cv2.waitkey(0)

cv2.imwrite('OIP.png', img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is error

> ```
> runfile('C:/Users/user/reading and writing an image.py', wdir='C:/Users/user')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "C:\Users\user\reading and writing an image.py", line 13, in <module>
>    cv2.imshow("oip" , img)
>
> error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
> size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
> ```

Comment: its more likely the image is not valid. Print img.shape, if the image path is valid you'll see the dimension otherwise it will throw you error.

Comment: The path to your image probably is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Could you that your `img` value isn't empty ? (This error indicates, that your file doesn't exists)

E.g with:

```py
import numpy as np

print(len(np.shape(img))) #should be equals or greater 2
```

Best regards